# Google Spreadsheet run script slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let's say I have a spreadsheet called A. When i run a script on spreadsheet A it will load very slowly and may cause timeout sometime. (I thought something was wrong with the function I created so i improved it - but still causing same result). However, once I make a copy of spreadsheet A (name it B). With the exact same code and functions spreadsheet B runs script rather fast. How is that possible when spreadsheet B is the exact same as spreadsheet A?

Comment: Please add the example script you are running. Without it, there are a number of different ways that the implementation may be slow on one sheet and not another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem. It is actually because of getScriptProperties in my google spreadsheet. So, in my old spreadsheet the getScriptProperties will take old data (whereby, when i create a new one, i does not exist). On the other hand, when I duplicate a new spreadsheet, it is running for the first time so it will take everything. What i did was deleteProperty of the old spreadsheet so that it can create a new Script Property (which will take new additions).

The code is as below:

```
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
scriptProperties.deleteProperty('test');
```